# Recortar o reducir URL con PHP

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando un script que reconoce las url cuando estas están dentro de un texto.

Código:

```
<?php
function findReplaceURL($text){
$reg_exUrl = '/(http|https|ftp|ftps)\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}(\/\S*)?/';

if(preg_match($reg_exUrl, $text, $url1)){
        return preg_replace($reg_exUrl, "<a href='".$url1[0]."' target='_blank'>".$url1[0]."</a>", $text);
        } else {
    return $text;
}
}

$texto = 'Este es un tecto con url: https://getbootstrap.com/';

$short_url = substr(md5($texto.mt_rand()),0,12); //recortar url

echo findReplaceURL($short_url);
?>
```

El problema es que dentro la variable `$short_url` estoy tratando de recortar la url pero el resultado es este: `0b21d1576f68`. Este es el resultado de lo que vengo haciendo mal y ya no se como solucionarlo.

NOTA: Si hago `echo findReplaceURL($texto);`, me reconoce la url.

Agradezco la ayuda!

Comment: ¿Qué resultado esperas? Creo que no estoy entendiendo la lógica de hacer un substring sobre una codificación md5, pero el resultado que es el que le pides: un substring con los 12 primeros caracteres del código md5.

Comment: Espero que la url se acorte cuando haga `echo findReplaceURL($short_url);` pero solo la url

Comment: Al hacer el proceso de substring sobre toda la variable texto le es estás pasando a la función una cadena de 12 caracteres variables procedentes del md5, la expresión regular no va a encontrar nada que reemplazar porque no hay nada con estructura de url. Si haces un echo $short_url verás que el texto que estás pasando a la función es del tipo 83ddf3aeeb1a, y es exactamente el mismo resultado que te devuelve la función.

Comment: Gracias Carmen, pude solucionarlo. Lo que hice fue agregar `substr(md5($url1[0]), 0, 5)` dentro de la función y funciona bien.

Comment: Perfecto, no hay de que